# Python pandas - using apply funtion and creating new columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 40 million records and I need to create 2 new columns (net_amt and share_amt) from existing amt and sharing_pct columns. I created two functions which calculate these amounts and then used apply function to populate them back to dataframe. As my dataframe is large it is taking more time to complete. Can we calculate both amounts at one shot or is there completely a better way of doing it

```
def fn_net(row):
    if (row['sharing']== 1):
        return  row['amt'] * row['sharing_pct']
    else:
        return row['amt']

def fn_share(row):
    if (row['sharing']== 1):
        return  (row['amt']) * (1- row['sharing_pct'])
    else:
        return 0

df_load['net_amt'] = df_load.apply (lambda row: fn_net (row),axis=1)
df_load['share_amt'] = df_load.apply (lambda row: fn_share (row),axis=1)
```

Comment: You can check the [Series.where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think numpy `where()` will be the best choice here (after `import numpy as np`):

```
df['net_amount'] = np.where( df['sharing']==1,              # test/condition
                             df['amt']*df['sharing_pct'],   # value if True
                             df['amt'] )                    # value if False
```

You can, of course, use this same method for 'share_amt' also.  I don't think there is any faster way to do this, and I don't think you can do it in "one shot", depending on how you define it.  Bottom line:  doing it with `np.where` is way faster than applying a function.

More specifically, I tested on the sample dataset below (10,000 rows) and it's about 700x faster than the function/apply method in that case.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({ 'sharing':[0,1]*5000, 
                  'sharing_pct':np.linspace(.01,1.,10000), 
                  'amt':np.random.randn(10000) })
```

Comment: Coding it your way ran ~30 min earilier. Problem solved thanks John :)